# kernel driver reading process memory from processID

Tags: c++, windows, kernel, driver

Quick question does anyone know if there is any signed driver that i could use to read processID memory?
I could make my owndriver to do this, but the problem is that i dont have $400 to get a code signing cert.

Comment: What is the overall goal you're trying to accomplish? What is your software supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is Windows, you need no driver. Just the [`ReadProcessMemory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553.aspx) API.

Comment: This is windows, I need to do it from kernel mode, i know about the normal  `ReadProcessMemory`

Comment: So you already have a driver? Why do you need another driver? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: because i need the driver to be signed and i dont have the money to sign one, so i was asking if anyone knew of a driver out there that does what i want and that is signed.

Comment: You need to read the memory of an arbitrary process, and you need to do it from kernel mode. How do you have execution in kernel mode, unless you already have loaded a driver? (In which case why do you need to load *another* driver?)